# Python regex for quoted printable chars

Tags: python, regex

How can I define a Python regex that matches all strings that start with double quotes (`"`), contain all printable chars (ASCII 32-126) and end with double quotes (`"`)?

Comment: For clarification, did you want to find occurrences of strings that **must** contain all printable characters, or **may** contain all printable characters ?  Also, how would you like a situation such as this to be handled: *The "quick "brown fox" jumped" over the lazy dog.* ?  Should the regex match `quick˽` and `˽jumped`, or `quick "brown fox" jumped` (where the ˽ denotes a space for reading purposes)?

Comment: Sorry, i mean may contain. In that situation the string to recognize are "quick" and "juped"

Comment: If "all" is a wrong description of the problem and it should be *only* instead, then it's the straightforward `^"[ -~]+"$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer your question:**

To do this for just `abc`, you'd have to write a regex that says: "start with `"`, then whatever; eventually `a`, then whatever, eventually `b`, then whatever, eventually `c`, then whatever, and finally `"`; or `b`, then whatever, eventually `a`, then whatever, eventually `c`, then whatever..." - and so on, for all `3! = 6` permutations.

```
# declarative

regex = '^".*(a.*b.*c|a.*c.*b|b.*a.*c|b.*c.*a|c.*a.*b|c.*b.*a).*"$'

# generative

import itertools

regex  = '^".*('
regex += '|'.join('.*'.join(p) for p in itertools.permutations('abc'))
regex += ').*"$'
```

However, if you try to do that for all printable characters, you'll probably run out of memory, as there are `(126-32)! = 108736615665674308027365285256786601004186803580182872307497374434045199869417927630229109214583415458560865651202385340530688000000000000000000000` permutations. So...

**To solve your problem:**

```
printables = {chr(i) for i in range(32, 127)}
def f(s):
    return s.startswith('"') and s.endswith('"') and printables < set(s)
```

Comment: Thanks Dan! This is better than regex!